# What could have caused a symbolic link to be deleted?

Tags: debian, symlink, reboot

About a week ago I changed the timezone on my VPS using the following command:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Eastern /etc/localtime
```

A couple of days later I get up in the morning and find the web server is down. Apparently the system restarted for some reason. Today I noticed that the time is wrong on the system because the symbolic link I made (shown above) was gone.

I thought that symbolic links are a permanent part of the filesystem that do not get deleted when a system restarts. Is this not true? What could have caused the symbolic link to be deleted?

Answer (score 1):

`timedatectl` alters the `/etc/localtime` symlink.

See the following for more info:

[timedatectl man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timedatectl.1.html)

[localtime man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/localtime.5.html)